# Is Apache XML security library compatibile with IBM's JDK

Tags: java, xml, security, apache

I developed an application that uses Apache XML security library for xml encryption and signing. It runs on SUN's JDK without any problems, however, IBM JDK gives me tons of problems.

It doesn't sign right (validation fails), pkcs11 provider fails to encrypt.

It seems that problem is because IBM provides their own security providers. 
I tried to comment out those providers (namely fips), and I almost managed to get same behaviour as on sun's jdk, except pkcs11 provider, which alwasy fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What version of the IBM JDK are you using?  Is there a stack trace that you get, or does the encryption simply produce bad output?

Comment: I don't suppose anyone has any more information on this. I'm having the same problem with XML signatures. Using the Sun JDK everything signs ok, but under the IBM JDK the signatures produced don't validate.

Answer (score 0):

Does this thread help - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1315965?

I had trouble in the past with an SSL enabled web application in Apache Tomcat because Tomcat defaults to using algorithm=SunX509 when you define a secure Connector. When using the IBM JDK, you must override by explicitly using algorithm=Ibmx509.

I'm guessing there's a similar issue at the root of your problem.